# How can I solve Duplicated Data Log Problem in Python stdout to txt file

Tags: python, logging, stdout

this is my first question. My code body is below, my data is duplicated and in a short time txt file is filling with too much data to handle, I could not solve the problem, I am new in programming and in python.

```
import logging
from time import sleep

x = 0

while True:

    x += 1

    print("you gotta be very careful",x)

    class Logger(object):

        def __init__(self, filename="Default.log"):
            self.terminal = sys.stdout
            self.log = open(filename, "a")

        def write(self, message):
            self.terminal.write(message)
            self.log.write(message)

    print("x, %.2f " %x) 

    sys.stdout = Logger("mylogfile.txt")

    sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: Actually, I think to add break command to my code thanks to this, after stopping the running program all the data in stdout can be copied to my log file which is a txt file. This is very much enough for me, I would like to get help to make this happen.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix code indentation / presentation and make sure it's a proper mcve (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How the entries of the log file look like (the message parameter)